# Enable context menu item for Java files

Tags: java, xml, eclipse-plugin

My Eclipse plugin defines menu items which are not enabled for the Java file selections but are enabled for other file formats. (.xml, .txt)

```
    <plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
      <objectContribution
            objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"
             nameFilter="*"            
            id="test1.contribution1">

         <menu
               label="MY Plugin"
               path="additions"
               id="test1.menu1">
            <separator
                  name="group1">
            </separator>
         </menu>

         <action
               label="Plugin Launcher"
               class="plugin.model.ExecutePlugin"
               menubarPath="test1.menu1/group1"
               enablesFor="*"
               id="test1.newAction">
         </action>

      </objectContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

I want to enable my menu items for the .java files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to specify the `adaptable` option:

```xml
 <objectContribution
        objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"
        adaptable="true"
        ... >
```

Note: The `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point is now deprecated, you should move away from using it.

Edit:

Specifying `true` for `adaptable` means that the system will use the `IAdapterManager` interface to check if the object `adapts` to the `objectClass` instead of requiring that the object implements the `objectClass` directly. This allows the view to use a different class for the actual view objects. The view code uses an `IAdapterFactory` to tell the adapter manager how to get the required class from the view object class.

Comment: you mean org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus extension point is now deprecated.

Then what is the other solution for that?

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.menus` is the recommended way to do menus now.

Comment: Please explain the use of "adaptable = true" syntax in the above code